# Date subtraction from columns in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have to two column, durasi and mulai and I want the total column reflect durasi - mulai .

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek2jw.png)

this is my controller.

```
public function postSimpanTambah()
    {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['nama']=Request::input('nama');
        $simpan['tanggal']=Request::input('tanggal');
        $simpan['deskripsi']=Request::input('deskripsi');
        $simpan['mulai']=Request::input('mulai');
        $simpan['durasi']=Request::input('durasi');
        $simpan['total'] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('durasi')) - \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', Request::input('mulai'));


        DB::table('lembur_karyawan')->insert($simpan);
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                alert('Berhasil menambahkan data');
                document.location='../user';
               </script>";
    }
```

this is my view :

```
<h3>Tambah User</h3>
                <hr>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo url('user/simpan-tambah') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Tambahkan Id">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Nama:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" value="<?php echo  Auth::user()->name. '';?>" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Tanggal:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal" placeholder="Tambahkan Tanggal">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Deskripsi:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deskripsi" placeholder="Tambahkan Deskripsi">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Mulai:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="mulai" value="17:00" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputIsiBerita"> Durasi:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="durasi" placeholder="Tambahkan Durasi">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kirim</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse">Reset</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick='location.href="<?php echo url('admin') ?>"' class="btn btn-inverse">Batal</button>
                    </div>
            </div>  

            </form>
```

and when i try to run i always get respond:
Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int

whats should i do ? have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for time difference.

```
$a = new DateTime(Request::input('durasi'));
$b = new DateTime(Request::input('mulai'));
$interval = $a->diff($b);
$x= $interval->format("%H:%i");
dd($x);
```

Comment: i have problem, example 17:00 - 23:02 result 6:2, should 6:58, and if 17:00 - 01:03 result 15:57 should 8:03, can that it? please..

Comment: what is the result you get for 17:00 - 23:02 ?.(is it 05:58 or 06:58)

Comment: if you need exact time,you must provide date also

Comment: sorry for my wrong question, before it. its  answer my question but, i have other problem when i input the durasi to 01:59 and mulai 17:00 result is 15:1 and its should be 08:59

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon provided methods([Link to methods](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)) to get difference between two date objects instead of logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

Check this .it will help you.here i am converting time to seconds and then substracting the seconds and then again converting result to hours and minutes.
 here durasi=01:59,mulai=17:00

```
$a = strtotime(Request::input('mulai'));
$b = strtotime(Request::input('durasi'));

$diff=$b-$a;
$time= gmdate("H:i", $diff);
dd($time);
```

Example:

```
     $a=strtotime('17:00');;
     $b=strtotime('01:59');
     $diff=$b-$a;
     $x= gmdate("H:i", $diff);

     OUTPUT: "08:59"
```

Comment: Thank you it work,can i ask again? how SUM data column total ?for  example i have two data in column total 01:45 and 02:25 result must be 4:10 . i have already try but my code only sum the hours not with the minute. what should do ?

Comment: you want to do add of two times.

Comment: can you give me a example you want to do

Comment: here my new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154656/sum-table-in-laravel-5

thanks please help.

Answer (score 0):

here my controller. for sum

```
public function getMei()
    {
        $data['users'] = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
                ->select('nama', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total_lembur'))
                ->groupBy('nama')
                ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
                ->first();

        return view('mei_user', $data);
    }
```

and my view :

```
<?php echo $users->{'total_lembur'} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding of two dates

```
 $a = strtotime("01:45")-strtotime("00:00");
 $b = strtotime("02:25")-strtotime("00:00");
 $seconds=$a+$b;
 $time= gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
 dd($time);
```