# SUM table in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[image: here my table and what i want to do]

SUM data column total ?for example i have two data in column total 01:45 and 02:25 result must be 4:10 . i have already try but my code only sum the hours not with the minute. what should do ?

here my controller. for sum

```
public function getMei()
    {
        $data['users'] = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
                ->select('nama', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total_lembur'))
                ->groupBy('nama')
                ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
                ->first();

        return view('mei_user', $data);
    }
```

and my view :

```
<?php echo $users->{'total_lembur'} ?>
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql

Comment: would you can explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timeSpent` ) ) ) as total_lembur')
```

MySQL autoconverts time to hours and you have to explicitly convert value by either TIME_TO_SEC or UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: owh oke thanks, did we can just show hours and minute ? 

if use : TIME_TO_SEC its show hours:minute:second

Comment: Use [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). E.g. Laravel employs it, when you apply `dates` mutator.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getMei()
{
    $data['users'] = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
            ->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(timeSpent)) as  total_lembur') 
            ->groupBy('nama')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
            ->first();
    return view('mei_user', $data);
}
```